# Proof by Contradiction on prime numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove using contradiction that any prime number greater than $3$ is of the form $6n \pm 1$.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 8):

Can you divide $(6n+2)$ by anything?  What about $(6n+3)$?

Comment: We usually do proof by contradiction questions using negations and disproving this, is there any way to do it like that?

Comment: @Christie Suppose we have a prime that is not of the form $6n \pm 1$. Then $p$ is of the form $6n + r$ for $r = 0,2,3,4$ and...

Comment: I don't know how to do that formally.  Maybe somebody else on here will.  You do know that every number is one of the following:$(6n\pm1),(6n\pm2),(6n\pm3)$.  Let's say $(6n\pm2)$ is prime, but we know it's not because it's divisible by 2.  So let's say $(6n\pm3)$ is prime.  Again, we know it is not because it's divisible by 3.  So all primes must be $(6n\pm1)$.  Oh, also rule out $(6n+0)$.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $N$ is a prime larger than $3$ and **not** of the form $6n\pm1$:

- $N\equiv0\pmod6\implies N$ is divisible by $6\implies N$ is not a prime
- $N\equiv2\pmod6\implies N$ is divisible by $2\implies N$ is not a prime (or $N=2$)
- $N\equiv3\pmod6\implies N$ is divisible by $3\implies N$ is not a prime (or $N=3$)
- $N\equiv4\pmod6\implies N$ is divisible by $2$ and $N\geq4\implies N$ is not a prime

Therefore, $N$ is a prime larger than $3\implies N\equiv1,5\pmod6\implies N\equiv\pm1\pmod6$